# Android SMS Sending behavior

Tags: android

I 've developed on SMS sending application for Android devices. A pop up opens up asking to choose sms applications (native app or mine ), whenever I try to send SMS to contact already present in Contact Book on my android device. But in case, if I try to resend a SMS already present in sms box in android device, no such pop up opens up ?

Answer (score 0):

Used this intent filter and my problem got solved

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
</intent-filter>
```